# How the entry(or root) component is loaded?

Tags: angular

Going by the global convention, lets assume my root component is named as `AppComponent` with its selector being `app-root` and root module as `AppModule`.

`AppModule` is bootstrapping `AppComponent`, which I assume, tells angular that this component is my root component.

But in index.html also we call `app-root`, which again calls the `AppComponent`.

My question is **why do I need to call the entry component in two places(index.html and appModule.ts)**.Why can't angular guess the root component defined from one place?

PS: i am eagerly looking of answer/suggestions/advice.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: angular defines which module to beload first in man.ts then there is ` bootstrap: [AppComponent]` in app module  which specifies which component to be loaded first

Comment: Because that's how they designed it to work

Comment: @JoelJoseph ,then in that case why should one call the selector of `AppComponent` in index.html

Comment: read the doc https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Comment: I'm really not sure what your hoping to get from this question. It's like that because the architects of angular decided that was the best way to do it. You seem to think that it isn't and want it to bootstrap itself, which would be perfectly possible. But both approaches have pros and cons. It just so happens that the guys at angular chose this particular architecture..that's about the long and short of it really.

Answer (score 1):

The `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` statement tells Angular which `Module` to bootstrap (usually the `AppModule`).

Inside of the bootstrapped `Module` you have a `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` statement which defines the `Component` that will be used to bootstrap the application.

And finally, in your `index.html` file you must specify the root component using it's selector (usually `app-root`).

The reason for the last part is so that Angular can actually find the element to be bootstrapped and initialise it. It is not uncommon to wrap your root component in other HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning bootstrap component (AppComponent) in AppModule is to tells angular that this component is root component.

> Why you are mentioning in index.html again?

Angular basically won't renderer any component untill you create a tag of it. or create it dynamically.

Angular can't create a tag of a `app-root` inside body on its own because as we developer have some requirement to put the `app-root` inside some `div` tags.

Comment: So I gues the real question is "Why doesn't angular create the component dynamically given it has the reference to the component in the bootstrapped module. Why do you (also) have to declare it directly in the index.html"

Answer (score 0):

To get started, if you put a selector (`say <app-root>`) in your plain HTML tag file, no browser will recognize the tag, since it is not a valid HTML element. This is where angular comes in. When you "bootstrap" the angular application, you basically tell the browser what all tags it can recognize. This is done by defining the components (and hence the selectors) in the `bootstrap` of the `AppModule`.

Once the browser knows the `<app-root>`, angular takes over the rest and your application is loaded.

So, you are not call the entryComponent at two places. In `index.html`, it is just a place where your angular application will be placed. In `AppModule`, you did it so the browser sees the custom tags as valid HTML elements.

Answer (score -1):

An `NgModule` describes how the application parts fit together. Every application has at least one Angular module, the root module that you bootstrap to launch the application. By convention, it is usually called `AppModule`.

After the `import` statements is a class with the `@NgModule` decorator.

The `@NgModule` decorator identifies `AppModule` as an `NgModule` class. `@NgModule` takes a metadata object that tells Angular how to compile and launch the application.

declarations—this application's lone component.
imports—import BrowserModule to have browser specific services such as DOM rendering, sanitization, and location.
providers—the service providers.
bootstrap—the root component that Angular creates and inserts into the index.html host web page.

[More details Angular official docs](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping)